# the user must login the page,after getting permission from admin

Tags: laravel-5

The user register his/her details in the register page and send email to administrator.Now the administrator need to give permission to the user to login the page.What is the way to get the permission from administrator

Comment: You should post what you have already done to achieve this and what you have already tried (code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: Add a boolean field called 'active' in users table. Set the default value for active as 0;

Step2: Add those following code to Auth controller.

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'active' => true
        ];
    }
```

Job done.

Now until, the active field is set to true, user won't be able to login. And offcourse, admin should be able to set true to active field after users has done their initial registration.

I have tested this code on Laravel 5.2 with laravel default AuthController.

Comment: thanks a lot its worked for me but i used normal controller not auth controller